# How can I convert an SQL primary key in JSON to a javascript object key with the other data as it's value

Tags: javascript, sql, json

Whenever I read all my data from a database table and receive it as JSON from my API, I get my data like this (`unique_name` being the primary key in this example):

```json
[{"unique_name":"alice", "age":18, "city":"kansas"},{"unique_name":"bob", "age":20, "city":"chicago"}]
```

In my javascript application, however, I need my data to be formatted like so:

```js
const myData = {alice: {age:18, city:"kansas"}, bob: {age:20, city:"chicago"}}
```

I guess this could be done with object mapping of some sort, but I'm afraid this would be too slow with a lot of entries. Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: You can do it with `forEach()` or `reduce()`.

Comment: There's no built-in way, you need to construct the new object in a loop of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real problem to map a lot of entries.
If you want more performences you should do it server side (eg: on a nodejs server)

You can simply use a `.forEach()`

Exemple (not complete so you just get the idea)

```
const myData = {};
mySQL.forEach(entry => myData[entry.unique_key] = entry)
```